# if X is complete, and $f^2$ is a contraction prove that $f $ has a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: X \to X $ such that for $f^2 $ we have the contraction property, and $X$ is a complete metric space. Prove that f has a unique fixed point.

I have already seen a correct proof of what I am asking, but still I haven't been able to analyse the exact answer I gave in an exam, and especially, I am not able to see a mistake, and maybe there are several mistakes. So maybe someone can help me with that?

The "proof" I gave is:

First we see that there exists at least a fixed point $a \in X$:

Let's suppose, by contradiction, that a fixed point doesn't exist, meaning
$f(a) \neq a $ for all $a \in X$ . As $ f(a) - a \neq 0 $, then

$ d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a) $.

As $X$ is complete, then $f(X) \subset X $. So,

$f^2(a) \subset f(a) $ for some $a \in X$.

As $X$ is complete and the contraction property holds, $f$ is continuous. This imples that

$ \lim_{x\to a} f(a) = a $, and

$ \lim_{x\to a} f(f(a)) = f (\lim_{x\to a} f(a)) = f(a) $ .

Then, $ d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a) $

$\Rightarrow d(f(a), a) \le \alpha d(f(a),a)$ ,

but $\alpha \in (0,1) \Rightarrow d(f(a), a) > \alpha d(f(a),a) $. This is a contradiction. Then it must be that $f(a) =a$.

Now we see that $a$ is the only fixed point:

Let's suppose that there exists $b \in A$ such that $b \neq a$ and

$ f(b) = b $,

$f(a) = a$. $f$ is a contraction, so

$ d(a, b) = d(f(f(a)), f(b)) \le \alpha d(a,b) $ . This is imposible, because if $\alpha \in (0,1) $ then $d(a,b) > \alpha d(a,b)$

because $d(a,b) > 0 $. This contradicts the hypothesis, so it shoud be that if $b $ is a fixed point of $f$, then  $a=b$.

Comment: What does $f(a) - a$ mean, if $a$ is an element of an arbitrary (complete) metric space? I suppose it should be $d(a,f(a))$

Comment: How do you justify
$$
d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a)
$$
It seems like you're assuming that $f$ has the contraction property.

Comment: it means that is f(a) and a are distinct then the distance is positive and the inequality holds

Comment: yes, f has the contraction property

Comment: But you were **not** told that $f$ has the contraction property, you were only told that $f^2$ (which I assume means $f \circ f$) has the contraction property.  If we knew that $f$ had the contraction property, we would just use the Banach fixed point theorem to get the rest of the way.

Comment: Notably, $f^2$ can have the contraction property *without* $f$ having the contraction property.  As an example, consider $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ given by
$$
f(x,y) = (2y,x/4)
$$
for which we find $f^2(x,y) = (x/2,y/2)$

Comment: you're right. Im confused, why i am asuming that $f $is a contraction?

Comment: The original question was *how do you justify*
$$
d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a)
$$
how are we supposed to arrive at this inequality, if not by assuming that $f$ is a contraction?

Comment: Also, if $a \in X$, what is $f^2(a) \subset f(a)$ supposed to mean?  The symbols don't make sense as you've used them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Mistakes in red, comment in red below the mistake)*

First we see that there exists at least a fixed point $a \in X$:

Let's suppose, by contradiction, that a fixed point doesn't exist, meaning
$f(a) \neq a $ for all $a \in X$ . As $\color{red}{ f(a) - a \neq 0 }$, then

$\color{red}{\textit{makes no sense in a metric space}}$

$\color{red} {d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a) }$.

$\color{red}{\textit{You seem to be assuming that $f$ is contractive}}$

$\color{red}{\text{As $X$ is complete, then $f(X) \subset X $}}$. So,

$\color{red}{\textit{This is because the codomain of $f$ is $X$, completeness has nothing to do with it}}$

$\color{red}{\text{$f^2(a) \subset f(a) $ for some }a \in X}$.

$\color{red}{\textit{This makes no sense: there is no inclusion between two points}}$

As $X$ is complete and the contraction property holds, $f$ is continuous. This implies that

$\color{red}{ \lim_{x\to a} f(a) = a }$, and

$\color{red}{ \lim_{x\to a} f(f(a)) = f (\lim_{x\to a} f(a)) = f(a) }$ .

$\color{red}{\textit{Makes no sense: the variable cannot appear as the limit result. From here on, I cannot make sense of anything else. }}$

Then, $ d(f(f(a)), f(a)) \le \alpha d(f(a),a) $

$\Rightarrow d(f(a), a) \le \alpha d(f(a),a)$ ,

but $\alpha \in (0,1) \Rightarrow d(f(a), a) > \alpha d(f(a),a) $. This is a contradiction. Then it must be that $f(a) =a$.

Now we see that $a$ is the only fixed point:

Let's suppose that there exists $b \in A$ such that $b \neq a$ and

$ f(b) = b $,

$f(a) = a$. $f$ is a contraction, so

$ d(a, b) = d(f(f(a)), f(b)) \le \alpha d(a,b) $ . This is imposible, because if $\alpha \in (0,1) $ then $d(a,b) > \alpha d(a,b)$

because $d(a,b) > 0 $. This contradicts the hypothesis, so it shoud be that if $b $ is a fixed point of $f$, then  $a=b$.

Comment: That's about what I got out of the proof too.  Well done

Comment: maybe I meant that $f^2(X) \subset f(X)$. Anyway I understand I did something very wrong. Thanks for the explanation.